# My ASP.NET Core MVC app (which runs locally with Docker) keeps incrementing the port number when I close and re-open Visual Studio

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app and every time I deploy it, it deploys on a higher port in the web browser. I set up this app by scaffolding everything through Visual Studio.

I am using .NET 8.0 LTS and I checked the Enable Docker box on the creation screen dialog. I also made sure that the solution was stored in the parent directory of the project as I plan on adding tests eventually. I also added local authentication. MVC apps do local authentication with ASP.NET Identity that I believe defaults to a local MySQL docker db and not the Azure platform.

The first thing I did was replace MySQL with Postgres and connected to the newly created Postgres container with `Npgsql`. The database works perfectly. I only had to make a couple changes like adding a new "ConnectionStrings" entry in `appsettings.json`, and changing the reference to this connection string in `Program.cs`. I also had to change the reference from  `UseSqlServer` to `UseNpgsql` in `Program.cs`.

When I start up Visual Studio, Docker Desktop has 2 running containers. 1 is a group of 2 containers: my postgres container and a container that I don't recognize called `adminer`. The Postgres container is always deployed at `5433:5432`, exactly as I set it, and `adminer` is always deployed on `8080:8080`.

My app is always deployed on a single container called "MY_PROJECT_NAME" from the image `MY_PROJECT_NAME:dev` at port INCREASING_NUMBER:8080 and `INCREASING_NUMBER - 1: 8081`... I never set this increasing number anywhere in my code. Btw I know it's obvious but `INCREASING_NUMBER` is a variable placeholder for a 5 digit number that is always increasing every time I open Visual Studio.

I searched the first port number and I can't find it anywhere in the project. How do I lock the browser deployment to a single port number?